# Set default multiline environment to align

Tags: lyx, align

In LyX, when I press Ctrl-Enter, I get `eqnarray`, which is generally deprecated. Is there a way to change the function of the Ctrl-Enter behavior to `align`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Document > Settings > Math Options. What do you have for "amsmath"? If you have "Do not load", the behavior is expected. If you have "Load automatically", then this is a [LyX bug](http://www.lyx.org/trac/ticket/2543) that has been fixed with [this commit](http://www.lyx.org/trac/changeset/87861bc6/lyxgit), which will be a part of LyX 2.2.0 that will be released soon (do you want to test [beta 2](ftp://ftp.lyx.org/pub/lyx/devel/lyx-2.2/lyx-2.2.0beta2/)?). If you want to work around the issue in LyX 2.1.x, change "Load automatically" to "load always".

Comment: Yep, it was 'Load automatically', changed it to 'load always' and it works. Thanks!